# D3 instead of jquery for dom management - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I've been recently playing around in d3 and I became aware that it has similarities with jquery. Would it be possible to use d3 instead of jquery for general dom management?

This is not a comparison question, however I'd be glad if the answers include valid points to pick one over another.

Comment: You cannot use the entire functionality of jquery even though in d3 dom Management possible which is simillar to jquery. However the remaining function of jquery is not possible in d3.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 is focused on creating/manipulating data-driven documents, that is creating/manipulating visual documents from your data by using D3's data/enter/exit methods.

jQuery is a general purpose js/ajax library which offers general js/ajax functionalities like updating cookies, but it doesn't offer data-driven functionalities of D3.

D3 has many visualization extensions and jQuery has many general web app extensions.

Both are dom manipulation js libraries, have css selectors and fluent api and are based on web standards which makes them look similar.